# Ubuntu constantly freezing - "read-only filesystem"

Tags: kubuntu, 19.10, hardware, crash

My system freezes regularly. Over a period of 10-20 seconds, everything breaks: all commands are "not found", internet connection breaks, soon after KDE exits and the only thing I can do (sometimes) is `to ctrl+alt+fX`. The programs already open and maximized become unresponsive much later; usually most of their functions work for a few minutes more (but, for example, Discord's voice breaks instantly).

A while ago, the only way to trigger this behavior was to start a resource-heavy program (a game, some memory chugging IDE), though it wasn't consistent either. Often I could keep playing much heavier games than usual for hours, and nothing happened.

Since today's morning, the freeze starts randomly even without heavy usage, in as little as 10 minutes from booting.

Every freeze requires me to shut down via holding the power button. Moreover, once I try to boot again, ONE or TWO (always one or two) times first a black screen with "checking media..." and then "boot device not found" (or something like that) is displayed, then - on the next try - the system seems to boot just fine.

Also, when I had been running Windows, there was no such problem. I'm fairly sure it appeared once I jumped to Linux though, or very shortly after.

If there's any additional info I can provide, please let me know.

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 19.10
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.3
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.67.0
Qt Version: 5.12.4
Kernel Version: 5.3.0-55-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 8 × Intel® Core™ i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz
Memory: 15,5 GiB of RAM
```

Below is a photo of what's seen if I `ctrl+alt+f2` during a freeze.
[image]

`sudo smartctl -all /dev/nvme0n1p3` looks... fine?

```
smartctl 7.0 2018-12-30 r4883 [x86_64-linux-5.3.0-55-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-18, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number:                       WDC WDS256G1X0C-00ENX0
Serial Number:                      172649803168
Firmware Version:                   B35500WD
PCI Vendor ID:                      0x15b7
PCI Vendor Subsystem ID:            0x1b4b
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x001b44
Controller ID:                      0
Number of Namespaces:               1
Namespace 1 Size/Capacity:          256 060 514 304 [256 GB]
Namespace 1 Formatted LBA Size:     512
Namespace 1 IEEE EUI-64:            001b44 8b444436ee
Local Time is:                      Tue Jun  9 22:31:38 2020 CEST
Firmware Updates (0x14):            2 Slots, no Reset required
Optional Admin Commands (0x0017):   Security Format Frmw_DL Self_Test
Optional NVM Commands (0x0016):     Wr_Unc DS_Mngmt Sav/Sel_Feat
Maximum Data Transfer Size:         32 Pages
Warning  Comp. Temp. Threshold:     85 Celsius
Critical Comp. Temp. Threshold:     88 Celsius

Supported Power States
St Op     Max   Active     Idle   RL RT WL WT  Ent_Lat  Ex_Lat
 0 +     8.25W    5.00W       -    0  0  0  0        0       0
 1 +     8.25W    3.50W       -    1  1  1  1        0       0
 2 +     8.25W    3.00W       -    2  2  2  2        0       0
 3 -   0.0500W       -        -    0  0  0  0    51000   10000
 4 -   0.0055W       -        -    0  0  0  0  1000000  100000

Supported LBA Sizes (NSID 0x1)
Id Fmt  Data  Metadt  Rel_Perf
 0 +     512       0         0
 1 -    4096       0         0

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
Critical Warning:                   0x00
Temperature:                        76 Celsius
Available Spare:                    100%
Available Spare Threshold:          4%
Percentage Used:                    12%
Data Units Read:                    30 621 036 [15,6 TB]
Data Units Written:                 33 132 105 [16,9 TB]
Host Read Commands:                 461 320 986
Host Write Commands:                637 846 910
Controller Busy Time:               123 432
Power Cycles:                       1 353
Power On Hours:                     12 993
Unsafe Shutdowns:                   243
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    0
Error Information Log Entries:      1
Warning  Comp. Temperature Time:    1886
Critical Comp. Temperature Time:    52

Error Information (NVMe Log 0x01, max 64 entries)
Num   ErrCount  SQId   CmdId  Status  PELoc          LBA  NSID    VS
  0          1     -       -  0x800c      -            0     0     -
```

Comment: You are describing symptoms with several possible causes. The most common is a dying (nearly-dead) HDD, so lookup how to run a SMART test on your HDD to confirm. Preserve any data that you value onto some other media immediately.

Comment: Read Only Filesystem suggests you've got a problem that couldn't be rectified so Ubuntu booted up in read-oly mode.  Run some SMART tests and check your `dmesg` output to see if there's any error messages in there about a broken file system or an I/O error on the device.

Comment: @user535733 @ThomasWard I have added the output of `sudo smartctl --all /dev/nvme0n1p3`, if you'd like to take a peek. `dmesg` returns just a ton of lines that sound like `apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord"`.

Comment: Let's first check your NVMe file system for errors. Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, open a terminal window by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T, type `sudo fdisk -l`, identify the `/dev/XXXX` device name for your "Linux Filesystem", then type `sudo fsck -f /dev/nvme0n1p3`, replacing `XXXX` with the number you found earlier. Repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors, then reboot and update your question with the results.

Comment: ps: Discord is nasty software. Especially in the snap version. It spies on you. It watches what other apps are running at the same time as Discord, and then reports them. It needs special permissions to run outside of its sandbox, or it bombs /var/log/syslog. Check to see if your disk is full, or if /var/log/syslog is huge.